# EC2 instance created with my own AMI with size up to T2.large missing DNS entries

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos, packer

I am having an issue in AWS since last few days. I've built two EC2 instances using my custom AMI one with T2.large and other with T3.medium.

I can ssh to both instances but I can't ping google or any other URL from T2 instance where as it works in T3 isntance.

both instances are on same VPC, subnet, SG and and built using same AMI.

```
T2 Insatance:
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search eu-west-2.compute.internal

[centos@ip-172-31-40-142 ~]$ curl google.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com; Unknown error

T3 Instance:
[centos@ip-172-31-21-112 ~]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search eu-west-2.compute.internal
nameserver 172.31.0.2

> [centos@ip-172-31-21-112 ~]$ curl google.com <HTML><HEAD><meta
> http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
> <TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY> <H1>301 Moved</H1> The document
> has moved <A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>. </BODY></HTML>
```

I've built a third instance with another AMI and T2 size and it works as normal. The only major difference I can see is cloud-init. New AMI has cloud-init 19.4 and old AMI has 18.5

Thanks,

Comment: If you have [SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) enabled, can you check that  policy of SELinux is not blocking this. Furthermore, If you have enabled [VPC Flow Logs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/), then you can trace vpc flow logs of EC2 network-interface to check network traffic flows and rejection if any.

Comment: SE Linux is set to permissive, I don't think this is blocking as the same settings on T3 instance works fine. If I restart network.service on T2 instance it is working as long as I don't reboot the instance. To me it is messing up my netowrk config manager settings on T2 instances only.